# How did I lose weight now?

Tags: weight-loss, workout

How am I losing weight now?

so, when I started working out, I went from a 44 inch waist to a 39.5, with a weight loss from 92 to 87 kgs. Ever since that, I pretty much quit working out. Whenever I did workout, it was not serious and got my heart beating barely enough. Eventually, I thought I was doomed to be fat and could not lose weight no matter what I did.

So, recently I went aboard. While I was there, I noticed my jeans were slightly loose now. I chose to ignore the fact until later. When I came back, I started drinking green tea. Its been about 62 days since I came back. I took green tea every day at about an average of 3 cups. Then later on I have purchased a treadmill. It has been 42 days since I've been running on it, and now my waist is 33.7.

Why wasn't I able to lose this weight before? Was there something wrong with my metabolism?

Comment: [How to ask](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) suggests making your question relevant to others besides yourself. For example, [this question](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24212/does-green-tea-causes-weight-loss-or-other-side-effects) answers part of your question, because it was asked in a generally useful way.

Comment: Unless you give details about your previous workout and diet, and current workout and diet, it's all just guesswork as evidenced by the two answers already. VTC as opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say because you don't give very precise information, but if I had to hasard a guess I would say that you experienced a combination of factors:

- Slightly elevated lifestyle expenditure: maybe you just moved more. Add to that consistent aerobic training and even if you "only" ran on it 20 to 25 minutes a day, it still builds up a large caloric deficit over time (especially if you are overweight)
- Slightly healthier lifestyle: you mentioned drinking green tea. Did it replace something else, like sweet soda? or treats? Not only does tea have some health benefits on its own, it's doubly the case when it takes the place of something that is less good (like a hot chocolate, or a starbucks capuccino, etc.)
- You experienced what is called the "whoosh" effect among people used to diet/cut weight. Weight loss doesn't always happen linearly and quite often tends to slow down, stall, and then happen as a burst after a refeed, due mainly to water retention.

Answer (score 0):

1. did you have a set plan? if not see [which of these 9 plans](http://www.nowloss.com/how-to-lose-weight.htm) best fits your lifestyle so you can consistently stick to a regular plan
2. what was your calorie intake? if you don't know then that could be a reason for unexplained weight loss so again see #1 for a solid plan
3. your workout. how did it differ in intensity, time and etc.
4. other factors like did you spend more time in the cold or under 66 F where your metabolism increases? Or did you lower your carb and increase your protein intake to flush out excess water

It could be any number of reasons but you need to STICK to something.